# Is it possible to stop Silverlight errors popping up an error dialog?

Tags: javascript, silverlight

When a Silverlight project throws an exception it ends up raising a "script error" dialog that needs to be acknowledged before proceeding.  We're using Silverlight for part of the content on a HTML page, but don't want the error dialog to appear if that content is unavailable.  Instead we are already writing the script error to a log and consider that sufficient.

Is it possible to prevent that dialog appearing on an uncaught exception?  Is the only solution to catch and handle all exceptions?  I have tried removing the "onError" parameter with its value of "onSilverlightError" but that made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the App.xaml.cs there will be "ReportErrorToDOM" event handler, completely comment all the code inside the handler, then you will not see any dialog box.

```
 private void ReportErrorToDOM(ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //string errorMsg = e.ExceptionObject.Message + e.ExceptionObject.StackTrace;
            //errorMsg = errorMsg.Replace('"', '\'').Replace("\r\n", @"\n");

            //System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval("throw new Error(\"Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " + errorMsg + "\");");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

your code might be little bit, just comment all the code inside the event handler then you should be ok.